# Error compilar proyecto Struts 2 con cambio de versión Java

Tags: java, java-8, compilar, struts2

He cambiado la versión de Java al compilar el proyecto pasando de la 1.7 a la 1.8, y al probarlo me sale el siguiente error:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Los datos de compilación del eclipse son los siguientes:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Podes compartir el `<%@ taglib %>` de tu proyecto? Creo que es un error en el uri path

Comment: Consejo para la próxima, tratá de no subir capturas, es mejor copiar y pegar los resultados. Facilita la lectura y seguimiento

Comment: el taglib es: <%@ taglib prefix="s" uri="/struts-tags"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Frameset//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-frameset.dtd">